# Maven wrapper inconsistent build result with locally installed maven

Tags: java, maven

I am running a Spring Boot project with Maven wrapper.

From a console, I can run `mvn clean install`. From Eclipse, I can run it with right-click -> Run as -> Maven install.

However, when using the Maven wrapper from command line:

`./mvnw clean install`

It doesn't work. I think it is because of the following lines at the top of the output when running the wrapper:

> [WARNING] The POM for org.apache.camel:camel-spring-boot:jar:2.21.0 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
>
> [WARNING] The POM for org.apache.camel:camel-core:jar:2.21.0 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
>
> [WARNING] The POM for org.apache.camel:camel-servlet:jar:2.21.0 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
>
> [WARNING] The POM for org.apache.camel:camel-sql:jar:2.21.0 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
>
> [WARNING] The POM for org.apache.camel:camel-test-spring:jar:2.21.0 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details

And finally, the entire build fails:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.camel.test.spring.CamelSpringBootExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(CamelSpringBootExecutionListener.java:41)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
```

I can force it to run by pointing out a directory to download into to get a fresh install:

`./mvnw clean install -Dmaven.repo.local=tmp`

My main use for the wrapper is in our CI environment, which basically forces the above line since we discard the image afterwards.

My locally installed maven has the following version information (`mvn -v`):

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_162, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.4.0-121-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

The wrapper has the following version information (`mvn -v`):

```
Apache Maven 3.5.2 (138edd61fd100ec658bfa2d307c43b76940a5d7d; 2017-10-18T09:58:13+02:00)
Maven home: /home/kajo/.m2/wrapper/dists/apache-maven-3.5.2-bin/7hf0mht29afbpa1e4v2d1a16p0/apache-maven-3.5.2
Java version: 1.8.0_162, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.4.0-121-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

I am curious as to why it doesn't work and what is the root of the problem. Compiling and testing the build takes a lot longer when I have to download fresh installs to get it work using the wrapper.

Comment: It looks like you might have corrupted poms for the camel artifacts in the local repo used by mvnw. You could try to clean the local repo used by mvnw. Additionally you could use -X to get more information on the build process.

Comment: @DrHopfen you were right about the camel artifacts, I simply removed them from the .m2 folder and the build passed without errors, the same result as having a clean directory. Perhaps there are differences in how strict Maven is with "broken" POMs?